# $7^{n+2}+1$ is divisible by 8

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

$n$ is an odd integer.

Use induction to prove $7^{n+2}+1$ is divisible by 8

When I use mathematical induction I get
$$7^{k+3}+1$$

then when I use the assumption  $$7\times 7^{k+2}+1\\
7\times (8m-1)+1\\
56m-6$$

How can I complete the answer? What went wrong?

Comment: Before you ask "why", ask "if". Say, $n=0$; then $7^{n+2}+1=7^2+1=50$. Is it divisible by 8?

Comment: This is true only for odd values of $n$. That follows pretty much immediately by taking the expression mod $8$.

Comment: $7 \equiv -1 \bmod 8 \implies 7^n \equiv (-1)^n \bmod 8$

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that this statement is **not** true.

Consider solving for $k$ such that $8|7^{k+2}+1$.

Then the above statement is equivalent to $$\bmod 8: (-1)^{k+2} \equiv -1$$ which means $k$ must be odd for this to hold, and it does not hold for even $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are establishing the conjecture for "odd integers" (I assume positive), you have two options:

1. Replace $n$ by $2n-1$ and go on with induction as usual.
2. Show that the conjecture is true for $n=1$. In the inductive step, assume that the conjecture is true for some $n=k$ and prove that it is true for $n=k+2$.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, using binomial :
Writing $7= 8-1$ and applying binomial theorem we get, $$7^{2n+1} + 1 = 1 + \sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{r}8^r (-1)^{2n+1-r} = 1+ (-1)^{2n+1} + \sum_{r > 0} 8^r \binom{2n+1}{r} (-1)^{2n+1-r}.$$
Thus $8$ divides the RHS.